# deploying .war file using root uri ("/")

Tags: tomcat

Using Tomcat for making java web application.

But when I click on run the application will be run into /${project-name}

How to deploy on root ("/") or somewhere else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do the following steps and share your feedback

```
1) Go to ur .settings folder of u r project
2) Open the below file notepadd++
3)  org.eclipse.wst.common.component
4) Paste below line and remove the existing line in above file
5) <property name="context-root" value=""/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple go to your web pages folder (which contains your statics).

Then make a folder named META-INF

Them make a file named context.xml

write into xml file

to deploy on root path also if you want to deploy on other uri just change the path value